# Some paths and settings being ignored in config

Tags: templating, users, config, activation, member

I've tried to set some things in my general.php config file but they're being ignored.

I have the following but all are being ignored. For example, when the user receives the activation email, upon clicking the link the account is activated but they're not taken to my template 'user/activation-success' but instead the homepage and also not automatically logged in, like I'm setting. Any ideas?

```
return array(
    'setPasswordPath' => 'user/set-password',
    'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'user/activation-success',
    'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true
);
```

I'm running 2.5.2757.

Updated to show my full config file:

```
<?php

return array(
    'setPasswordPath' => 'user/set-password',
    'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'user/activation-success',
    'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,

    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    ),

    '.local' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'userSessionDuration' => false
    ),

    '.co.uk' => array(
        'cooldownDuration' => 0,
    ),

    '.com' => array(
        'cooldownDuration' => 0,
    )
);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not already logged in with another account when you're testing this?

Comment: No, I'm using a different browser and ensuring that there is no logged in user on it. I've tried this many times now with no joy.

Comment: Is this your full general.php file, or is it just a pared-down version?

Comment: No but I've updated the above to show it. The domain based items (i.e. 'devMode' => true) are working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close!  Those config settings are off in no-mans-land right now.  If you want them to apply across all of your multi-environment configs, you need to move them into the `'*'` array like so:

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'setPasswordPath' => 'user/set-password',
        'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'user/activation-success',
        'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
    ),

    '.local' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'userSessionDuration' => false
    ),

    '.co.uk' => array(
        'cooldownDuration' => 0,
    ),

    '.com' => array(
        'cooldownDuration' => 0,
    )
);
```

Comment: Ah, don't know how I didn't figure that out. Thanks, all working now!